# Upgrade PCRE to 8.40 on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, yum, pcre, typo3

When I do `yum installed | grep pcre` I get:

```
pcre.x86_64           8.32-15-el7_2.1     @updates
pcre-devel.x86_64     8.32-15-el7_2.1     @updates
```

- **How do I upgrade** these to the most recent versions (currently 8.40)?
- **Do I have to uninstall the existing packages first** (I tried doing yum remove pcre and it looked like it was going to uninstall a million packages so I cancelled it)?
- **Can a precompiled repo be used** so I can continue using yum update or do I need to compile it?
- I saw a [PCRE install via compile tutorial](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/pcre.html) but am not sure if this is correct for CentOS.

*Reason Upgrade Needed: My CMS, TYPO3 8.7.2, requires a minimum PCRE 8.38.*

*Note: I'm hosting this myself on a dedicated server I own so don't have anyone to lean on.*

Comment: I compile this and several other programs for my C7 boxes, but I have specifc needs for this.  Each program I have custom built has the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` of the programs/libraries I have built in the startup.  If you find instructions saying to update anything under `/etc/ld.*`, ignore it, that is a dangerous path to go down unless you want to be a Linux package maintainer.  Just keep everything tucked away from the OS under `/opt` somewhere, if you must go this route.  Avoid doing this at all if you can.

Comment: @aaron I'm reading what you wrote but it's a little over my head. I don't think I saw anything that referenced `/etc/ld.*`. Is that something common I'd see when doing a compile on something for my particular server?

Comment: centos/redhat docs will suggest appending a file to include a system wide path to your libraries of packages you build, but your custom pcre will conflict with the OS provided packages and may cause issues for some things, or may not.  A chance not work taking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I upgrade these to the most recent versions (currently 8.40)?

First, ask yourself why do you need an update, what features can you not get? As to how, your next questions provide the answers.

> Do I have to uninstall the existing packages first (I tried doing yum
>   remove pcre and it looked like it was going to uninstall a million
>   packages so I cancelled it)?

Suggest use precompiled packages with yum and carefully examining the upgrade transaction before applying.

Having both the package and the source install will complicate things.

Consider rebuilding with a distro that maintains current versions like Fedora. It may be exhausting to install and test constant updates, but at least you do not have to hunt down or compile a recent package.

> Can a precompiled repo be used so I can continue using yum update or
>   do I need to compile it?

You may choose either. The package way is easiest when you find a repository that has what you want. The compile method requires you to install build dependencies and make it co-exist with any packages installed.

> I saw a PCRE install via compile tutorial but am not sure if this is
>   correct for CentOS.

Linux From Scratch scripts assume their distribution.
 They won't tell you which EL packages to install to make things happen, because they are not Red Hat based at all.

Also, a more through study of LFS will allow you to appreciate the differences between distributions.

Comment: I will eventually move to Ubuntu for the newer packages, but in the meantime since it's a hug job I need to patch this server since my CMS, TYPO3 8.7.2 requires a minimum of PCRE 3.38. I appreciate these comments but I was hoping someone could point me to specifics on the exact compile command and/or an rpm that would work? Thanks for the added understanding though!

Comment: We don't really do that level of step by step. If reading the install documentation is not sufficient, you probably are not  ready for compiling something for production use.  Couple options: Use the CentOS package and work around its complaints or problems. Switch to a newer distro and use their packages.

Comment: Thanks @john for honest feedback. I have compiled before but in this case I'd sure rather not. I will already taken your recommendation and starting the build of a new server and will migrate.

Answer (score 0):

god-is-love mentions CentOS 7.3.
I needed the update for the CSM Typo3 v8.7.2 on a Cloudlinux 7.3 (Centos 7.3) cPanel server, and CL provided me a beta update of PCRE 8.40.
If you're using CloudLinux as well you can ask CL support for a yum update string.
I am running 8.40 now.

Comment: I also use TYPO3 and is the reason I'm updating. TYPO3 8.7.2 requires a minimum PCRE version 8.38 and the default for CentOS 7.2 is PCRE 8.32 and nothing newer. This is on a standalone server of my own so I don't have anyone to ask for help sadly.

Comment: Ok. Maybe as a consolation: Typo3 might complain but my 2 websites upgraded to 8.7.2 worked without issues for a couple of weeks, only the warnings annoyed me.Since today (pcre 8.40) warnings are gone.

Comment: I have had the same experience. It's listed in red in the install tool but I have not noticed any adverse effects in real life. Nevertheless, I am fixing the problem by just migrating to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS which meets the requirements.